# How to change nested properties in MongoDB using Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have an object in my MongoDB:

```js
{
  "title": "Amazing Spider Man 2",
  "description":
    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
  "image": "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/35357.jpg",
  "price": 150,
  "screen": 1,
  "dates": [
    {
      "date": "2014-02-01T09:28:56.321-10:00",
      "rows": [
        {
          "seats": [
            { "booked": true },
            { "booked": true },
            { "booked": false }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seats": [
            { "booked": false },
            { "booked": true },
            { "booked": false}
          ]
        },
        {
          "seats": [
            { "booked": false },
            { "booked": true},
            { "booked": false }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
```

I want update "booked" property using Express. And I have no idea how to do it in the best way :) 
I am very new to Node.js and Mongo, so I would be very thankful for any help. 
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have express running and configured in the app?

Comment: Yes. I've already wrote simple get, post routes.

Comment: How are you accessing mongodb in node, through mongoose?

Comment: Yes, I'm using mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the document using [the update array operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/)!.

this is from mongodb shell
use 0 to indicate the position within the array

```
db.getCollection("your collection name").update(criteria, $set: {"dates.0.rows.0.seats.0.booked" : false})
```

you can learn from the Array Update Operators in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/

Comment: Thanks for response! But what if I want to receive info for eg. about indexes from frontend? How can I do something like that: `dates.${req.body.dateIdx}....`?

Comment: if it's an integer value you won't have a problem